# error: Undefined property: News::$form_validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

I am new to the codeigniter and trying the tutorials in the user guide. But i stuck i the third tutorial which is for the create news items. Here in my controller section it is giving the following error:

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: News::$form_validation

Filename: controllers/news.php

Line Number: 44

and the code that i used in the controller section is

```
public function create()
{
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
    $this->load->view('news/create');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
else
{
    $this->news_model->set_news();
    $this->load->view('news/success');
}
}
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you have used `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: this is the line:    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');

Comment: I jst copy pasted the given tutorial. I didn't chage anything in it.

Comment: @LearneR, that shouldn't make a different as the function will return boolean, and doing a strict comparison for a boolean value would still be the same as using `==` using `===` would be *slightly* faster though.

Comment: @user1929236, what does `var_dump($this->form_validation);` output?

Comment: @user1929236, are you sure you are extending the Controller class by doing this? `class News extends CI_Controller {`

Comment: yes, i have made the previous tutorrail by CI_COntroller with the same. It works for me. But this doessn't work.

Comment: @cryptic sorry, but i don't know a lot about codeigniter. I just strted with it.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/186954/ I think this one is similar to my problem but in the end i cannot understand how this guy solves it.

Comment: @user1929236 In `application/config/autoload.php` look for `$autoload['libraries']` and add `form_validation` to it. Let's see if it will work if it is auto-loaded.

Comment: @user1929236, so did auto-loading it work? Btw, I'm a girl =oP

Comment: YES that worked mam. N sorry for the misunderstanding mam.

Answer (score 1):

Propably you don't specify loading model. So include this before

```
$this->load->model('news_model');
```

after that you can call

```
$this->news_model->set_news();
```

or edit config\autoload.php and set your model, then you can use after successfully validation

```
news_model::set_news();
```

or you can that in constructor, like this:

```
class MySomeClas extend CI_Controller
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('news_model');
 }
```

and call models right