# Message: Undefined property: Users::$form_validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

im currently trying to change my application from MySQL database to MongoDB database. My project requires to compare two of these, and my MySQL code was working and now it gives me this error.

Stack Trace:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: `Users::$form_validation` Filename: `controllers/users.php` Line Number: 26

Error line:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
```

Code:

```
<?php
class Users extends CI_Controller{
    public function register(){ 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name','trim|required|max_length[50]|min_length[2]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name','Last Name','trim|required|max_length[50]|min_length[2]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|max_length[100]|min_length[5]|xss_clean|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|max_length20]|min_length[6]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|max_length[20]|min_length[6]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2','Confirm Password','trim|required|max_length[50]|min_length[2]|xss_clean|matches[password]');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $data['main_content']='users/register';
            $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);    
        }else{
            if($this->User_model->create_member()){ 
                $this->session->set_flashdata('registered','Registered successfully');
                redirect('home/index'); 
            }
        }
    }

    public function login(){
        //$this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');      
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[50]|xss_clean');        

        $collection = $this->database->users;

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Sorry, this username doesn't exist.');
            redirect('home/index');
        } else {

        $username=$_POST['login'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $user_id = $collection->findOne(array('username' => $username, 'password' => md5($password)));
          // $username = $this->input->post('username');
          // $password = $this->input->post('password');


           $user_id = $this->User_model->login_user($username,$password);


           if($user_id){

               $user_data = array(
                       'user_id'   => $user_id,
                       'username'  => $username,
                       'logged_in' => true
                );

               $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

               redirect('home/index');
            } else {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Sorry, this username doesn't exist.');
                redirect('home/index');
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout(){

        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('user_id');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        redirect('home/index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide the stack trace for the error?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Users::$form_validation

Filename: controllers/users.php

Line Number: 26

Comment: please include this in the question

Comment: [A comment on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116920/error-undefined-property-newsform-validation-in-codeigniter#comment19538641_14116920) points to `form_validation` possibly not being autoloaded...

Comment: You did not loaded the form_validation.Try to search at google or read [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing config/autoload.php worked for me, just add form_validation in autoload :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');
```

Answer (score 2):

This because of ***failed to load relevant library***

**Method 01**

```
public function  __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->load->helper('form');
  }
```

**Method 02**

in `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');
```

[Form_Validation Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this method-

```
     public function  __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->load->helper('form');
  }
```